# Node equivalent to index.html

Tags: node.js

I'm coming from a LAMP background and want to test out node for production.

What seems a little confusing to me is that in Apache url's map to folders, and the server will automatically look for an index.html or index.php if you aren't re-writing urls.

What would the equivalent be in node?

I'm thinking it'd be something like checking the request url and matching it, then loading a specific node module which runs the app.

This might seems simple for a single app, but we run tons of client apps on our server so i'm used to having different frameworks in different folders and index.php just runs it.

---

to be more specific. i'm currently running a few codeigniter and wordpress installations on our server. so i'd want to run a few node apps/frameworkds in different 'subfolders'

Comment: Node isn't a file server, it's an application server. You would start it like this: `node app.js`. The rest depends on how you write your application, i.e. the code inside `app.js`.

Comment: There is no `mod_node` for apache. Your doing it wrong.

Comment: so if i have multiple apps running on one machine i have multiple instances of node running?

Comment: @wayne correct, generally you put all these node http servers behind a single load balancer.

Comment: @Raynos: There is a mod_node, though I don't recommend it for production enviornment: https://github.com/aredridel/mod_node

Comment: @MauvisLedford only a madman would think using mod_node for apache was not retarded.

Comment: @wayne Whatever you do, don't use Node with Apache pleeease :)

Comment: haha, thanks guys. no plans to use apache :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Node you don't really use Apache. It's similar to Ruby in that is runs its own web server.

However, you can probably get Apache to run Node files using [mod_node](https://github.com/aredridel/mod_node). As far as I know this is non-standard though and you definitely lose the "non-blocking" advantages of Node. But for experimenting (and not load testing) it's fine.

Check out [Express](http://expressjs.com/) if you're looking for an MVC architecture written in Node.

If you're just looking to run the most basic sample web server, just run the example hosted on the main page: http://nodejs.org/

Lastly, I had that same issue you are experiencing where I have one box hosting a lost of stuff and Apache taking up port 80. The answer here is to use a reverse proxy like Nginx to run on port 80 and redirect traffic to Apache / Node / Ruby / etc. Best of both worlds and since Nginx is written non-blocking you still gain the benefits of node.

I actually wrote an in-depth blog article about this a few months ago:
http://readystate4.com/2011/07/15/nginx-apache-and-node-all-living-harmony/